# return array of phrases by substracting each string from the previous one

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have an array of object like this:

```
const sentences = [
  { reference: "Beautiful" },
  { reference: "Is beautiful" },
  { reference: "This forest is beautiful" },
];
```

As you see from the first one (first object in the array) to the last one we added word or words to shape a meaningful sentence right?

Now I want to substract each string from the previous one and return an array of phrases like this:

```
['This forest', 'Is', 'Beautiful']
```

Note that we substract it like this:

```
third obj: "This forest is beautiful" - "Is beautiful" = 'This forest'
second obj: "Is beautiful" - "Beautiful" = 'Is'
```

and the last one is just returned:

```
first obj: 'Beautiful'
```

The issue is the replace method which I used in the below code dosnt care about case insensetivity and it replaces the first occurance of the phrase not the last one:

To be clear look at the code below and the desired result I explained at the end of the code:

```js
const sentences = [
  { reference: "Beautiful" },
  { reference: "Is beautiful" },
  { reference: "This is beautiful and This forest is beautiful" },
];

console.log(getSentences());

function getSentences() {
    const result = [];
    
    for(let i = sentences.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if(i - 1 >= 0) {
            const res = sentences[i].reference.replace(sentences[i - 1].reference, '');
            result.push(res);
        } else {
            result.push(sentences[i].reference);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// desired result of the code would be:
//["This is beautiful and This forest", "Is", "Beautiful"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it is best to use a regular expression. Since part of your expression is dynamically generated, you need to build one using the RegExp object:

```js
const sentences = [
  { reference: "Beautiful" },
  { reference: "Is beautiful" },
  { reference: "This is beautiful and This forest is beautiful" },
];

function getSentences() {
  const result = [];

  for (let i = sentences.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (i - 1 >= 0) {
      var regexp = new RegExp(sentences[i - 1].reference + "$", "ig");
      const res = sentences[i].reference.replace(regexp, '');
      result.push(res);
    } else {
      result.push(sentences[i].reference);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(getSentences());
```

Comment: desired result of the code would be:
`["This is beautiful and This forest", "Is", "Beautiful"]`

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Now fixed.

Comment: We should look for matches from the end of each string not from the start

Answer (score 0):

Another technique.  Fold the sentences into a new array, starting with an empty string and removing the previous one from the end of each subsequent one.  This leaves us with an unneeded empty string, which we remove with `slice`.  The result is backward, so we `reverse` the results:

```js
const getSentences = (sentences) => sentences .reduce (
  (r, {reference}, i) => [...r, reference.replace (new RegExp(` ${r[i]}$`, 'i'), '')], 
  ['']
) .slice (1) .reverse ()

const sentences = [{reference: "Beautiful"}, {reference: "Is beautiful"}, {reference: "This is beautiful and This forest is beautiful"}]

console .log (
  getSentences (sentences)
)
```

This is a pretty bizarre requirement, but I think this code fulfills it.